# Does increasing the magnitude of the pendulum angle cause its time period to be underestimated?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, anharmonic-oscillators

The pendulum equation states that the time period $T=2π\sqrt{l/g}$. This is based on the small angle approximation where we approximate  l 
$$\frac{{\rm d}^2 θ}{{\rm d}t^2 }= -\frac{g}{l}\sin θ \approx  -\frac{g}{l} θ.$$
So my question is, since the magnitude of $\sinθ$ is smaller than $θ$, through the approximation will the angular acceleration be larger reality, so its speed is overestimated and the time period smaller than without the small-angle approximation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show bigger amplitude of physical pendulum means bigger period](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158917/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The easy way to see this is that physically, as the amplitude approaches 180 degrees, the period must approach infinity.